# Use logger after task completion using sbt 1.4.x

Tags: scala, sbt

Starting with sbt 1.4.x it does not seem possible to log using `streams.value.log` logger anymore after the associated task is completed (more details at [sbt/sbt#5731](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/5731)).

This is used by the [scalajs-bundler](https://github.com/scalacenter/scalajs-bundler/issues/389) sbt plugin to log outputs from webpack-dev-server even when the task is complete. I found a global logger available under `state.value.globalLogging.full` fixing my issue, but as there is not too much documentation about it I am not sure it is the correct fix for my use case. Can someone validate the fix or point me to some documentation please?

Note: it is possible to fix the issue using `ThisBuild / useLog4J := true` (to use pre sbt 1.4.x loggers) but it is leaking large amounts of memory.